# Send formArray as one object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using [mat-stepper single form](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#using-a-single-form) for my stepper. when i do API call it sends data as an array of objects like this:

```json
[ 
  { 
    "product": "lifeci", 
    "gender": "F", 
    "birthDate": "1999-04-23T10:58:53.839Z", 
    "payFrequency": 12, 
    "subLimit": "100"
  }, 
  { 
    "currency": "USD", 
    "amount": "15000", 
    "period": 3 
 }
]
```

I would like to send data as one object like this:

```json
{ 
  "gender": "string", 
  "birthDate": "2021-04-23T11:37:01.738Z",
  "period": 0, 
  "payFrequency": 0, 
  "amount": 0, 
  "subLimit": "string", 
  "currency": "string",  
  "product": 0 
}
```

this is my form:

```
    this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      formArray: this._formBuilder.array([
        this._formBuilder.group({
          product: ['lifeci', Validators.required],
          gender: ['', Validators.required],
          birthDate: ['', [Validators.min(18), Validators.max(50)]],
          payFrequency: [12],
          subLimit: ['100']
        }),
        this._formBuilder.group({
          currency: ['USD', Validators.required],
          amount: ['15000', Validators.required],
          period: ['', Validators.required],
        }),
      ])
    });

      onSubmit() {
        this.service.calculate(this.formGroup.value).subscribe(
          (res:any)=>{
            console.log(res);
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
      }
```

**service.ts**

```
    export class LifeciService {
    
      readonly API_SERVER = "API_URL";
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      calculate(formData) {
        return this.http.post(this.API_SERVER + '/Calculate', formData);
        }
    
    
    }
```

how can i do it?

Comment: you should show us api service also.

Comment: hi! i edited my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple transformation using javascript `reduce` function to transform the data to the desired structure

```js
const initial = [ { "product": "lifeci", "gender": "F", "birthDate": "1999-04-23T10:58:53.839Z", "payFrequency": 12, "subLimit": "100" }, { "currency": "USD", "amount": "15000", "period": 3 } ];

const reduced = initial.reduce((prev, next) => ({...prev, ...next}), {})
console.log(reduced)
```

In your case this can be implemented like below

```
      onSubmit() {
        const formArrayData = this.formGroup.get('formArray').value;
        const data = formArrayData.reduce((prev, next) => ({...prev, ...next}), {})
        this.service.calculate(data).subscribe(
          (res:any)=>{
            console.log(res);
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer how can i implement this with my service? i did something like that
but it doesnt work:
onSubmit() {
  const initial = [this.formGroup.value];
  const reduced = initial.reduce((prev, next) => ({...prev, ...next}), {})
  console.log(reduced);
  this.service.calculate(reduced).subscribe(
    (res:any)=>{
      console.log(res);
    },
  );
}

Comment: Use `const initial = this.formGroup.get('formArray').value`